# Using native javascript to select HTML & SCRIPT tags and their data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, jquery-1.9

How can I select the element of HTML and get its data attribute without using jquery?

For instance, I have this html tag with some data attribute,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js" data-directory='{"base_url":"http://localhost/mywebsite/","core_package":"base/","local_package":"base/"}'>
```

This is a jquery way,

```
var directories = $('html').data('directory');
```

What about javascript's native way?

Also, how can I select the script tag and get its attribute data?

For instance, I have this script tag,

```
> <script
> data-main="http://localhost/mywebsite/local/view/javascript/base/main"
> src="http://localhost/mywebsite/core/view/javascript/base/ext/require/require.js"></script>
```

a jquery way,

```
var base_url = $('script[src$="require.js"]').attr('src').split(/\b(?:core|local)\b/)[0];
```

But I need a javascript native way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

**1.** .getAttribute("data-directories")

```
var directories = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("data-directory");
```

**2.** .src or .getAttribute("src") works the same

```
var base_url=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src.split(/\b(?:core|local)\b/)[0];
```

For newer browsers [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) can be used like jQuery selectors which is of course smarter if there are more than one script on the page

```
var base_url=document.querySelector('script[src$="require.js"]').src.split(/\b(?:core|local)\b/)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var base_url = document.querySelector('script[src$="require.js"]').getAttribute("src").split(/\b(?:core|local)\b/)[0];
```

Comment: Nice. I keep forgetting that one

Answer (score 1):

Use [.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

```
var selector=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

//Using DOM's getAttribute() property
var dataAtributte=selector.getAttribute("data-directory");
//retuns  {"base_url":"http://localhost/mywebsite/","core_package":"base/","local_package":"base/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you want to do it with native JavaScript when with jQuery is so much easier and you know how to do it ?

The analogue of `$('html')` selector is `document.getElementsByTagname("html")` which will return you an array of elements so you have to get the `[0]` index for the first `html` tag.
Then for your attributes you should do something like `.getAttribute("attr-name")` in your case attr-name is data-directory. So finally you get a row like

`document.getElementsByTagname("html")[0].getAttribute("data-directory");`

For your second problem just do the same but chage the `Tagname` value and the `getAttribute` value.

`document.getElementsByTagname("script")[0].getAttribute("data-main");`